# Does $\operatorname{End}_R(R)\cong R^{\text{op}}$ still hold when $R$ doesn't have an identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, rngs

When I try to prove that $\operatorname{End}_R(R):=\text{Hom}_R(R,R)\text{(left)}\cong R^{\text{op}}$, I used the map $f \mapsto f(1)$, which requires $R$ to have an identity. Is it really necessary to assume that $R$ has an identity? If not, is there an counterexample for this?

Comment: $\operatorname{End}_R(R)$ has an identity, so for an isomorphism $End_R(R)=R^{op}$ to hold, $R$ must have an identity

Answer (score 3):

The endomorphism ring always has an identity. If the ring $R$ hasn't one, you're doomed.

For a more spectacular failure, consider $R$ to be the Prüfer $p$-group, with trivial multiplication. Its endomorphism ring is the ring of $p$-adic integers, which has even larger cardinality.

Comment: oh~~~sorry for this stupid question...

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by trivial multiplication here?

Comment: @TiWen $ab=0$, for all $a,b\in R$.